Why is Portuguese 'mundo' transcribed phonemically /ˈmũ.du/ but for other languages not even phonetic transcription records a "deviation" from /n/?
For a short version of the question, see at the end EDIT AFTER COMMENTS:

I know about the Differences between phonemic and phonetic transcriptions, and I am referring to the phonemic transcription, and, as said in an answer under above question,

Phonemes are what we hear. Phonetics is what we say

But what I hear in my native Romanian is sometimes not what I see transcribed in any of the two.

Portugues mundo has this pronunciation:

IPA: /ˈmũ.du/

(Rural Central Brazil) IPA: /ˈmũ.dʷ/


Does that mean that Portuguese people are so aware that N in mundo is assimilated and that the preceding vowel is nasalized that it has entered the phonemic transcription, while speakers of other languages don't feel the need for that? Or maybe they don't even notice it?
Or maybe the nasalization in (say, Romanian) is weaker? Even so, shouldn't it be marked more often?
In fact, I cannot find an example in Romanian where N preceding a consonant is pronounced as an alveolar (like in name=nume), e.g. in words like cânt (to sing) or bancă (bank): we go from the preceding vowel to the following consonant without ”acting” a N, while the preceding vowel is nasalized (I hear [kɨ̃t] and [bãkə]).
Isn't the same for English too? I see in fact that English bank is transcribed phonemically /bæŋk/. But not even the phonetic transcription of Romanian cânta reflects an alteration of N: [kɨn'ta].
Is that because there isn't a sign for nasal ɨ? Or is it because in fact Romanian N is not assimilated?
I note that in English contain is /kənˈteɪn/ and convene is /kənˈviːn/ - but what would it be their phonetic transcriptions [xxx]?
Romanian a conveni has a very soft/low N, it is almost like French in my opinion, yet is transcribed [con.veˈni]. It is very embarrassing for me to find that the audio transcription at the same Wiktionary address is just the result of confirming the above transcription and not at all what we hear in the language!
For example, take the expression "ce-ți convine ție nu-mi convine mie" (what's convenable for you it isn't so for me) - audio HERE. I hear a very "Frenchy" ON there! - and that's how I would say it.
Or "la început a fost cuvântul" (at the beginning was the word") - audio HERE or HERE: is there an [n] there?

I realized I have asked multiple questions. That was done in order to illustrate what I mean (share my lack of knowledge). - But please try to answer the question in the title, mainly.

EDIT AFTER COMMENTS:
From exchanges in comments I ended up with a succint form of my problem. Hear the following 2 pronunciations:

Portuguese mundo /ˈmũ.du/
Romanian bandit

Is it the case that only the first involves assimilation of N and nasalization of the previous vowel?

I don’t find the these examples like convine to be nasalised or anything other than expected.  Portuguese or French is quite different in this regard.

That says "rural central Brazil".  Not all Portuguese. mundo comes from mundus and is monde in French and mundo in Spanish too. The n does not disappear at all.

@Lambie - That is the Wiktionary page for the word, first line is Portuguese, second is Brazil. Not only that, but an outdated form was mũdo.

@AdamBittlingmayer - I realize my post is very impressionistic, I realize French is very different, I was just making an analogy. --- I am surprised that not even the phonetic transcription marks a difference between alveolar (almost dental) N (like in nume) and that in bancă. It is as much a difference as between English N in name and that in bank (n/ŋ). I dont know what sign [xxx] should be used for N of bancă or convine, but it should mark some difference from [n] of nume=name.

It says archaic in the second one and abbreviation. So, it's not common to Portuguese at all. Just believe me. I'm fluent in Portuguese and there are a lot of pronunciation differences in places like Minas Gerais.

@AdamBittlingmayer - Even considering French bandit /bɑ̃.di/ - Romanian has the neologism that is graphically identical. But its pronunciation too (I mean the AN part) is much closer to French pronunciation (and that not because of some French influence - it is just by the normal use of these sounds in Romanian) than it is to AN in ani =years etc. I'd  say it's /bandit/ but [bɑ̃.dit]. I may be wrong abou [ɑ̃], but I here nothing like [n].

@Lambie - You might say that the Wiktionary is wrong, in which case please give me the correct transcription. But you seem to mean that I am reading wrong that page. I beg to differ: what it says is that it doesn't mention any difference in Brazilian from standard Portuguese except a specific rural case etc. The first line is Portuguese (Brazilian too), the second is non-standard Brazilian.  - As for older form being an abbreviation that only means an abbreviation of the written form = reflecting the pronunciation!

All this is for Minas Gerais and places like that. I'm saying it is not anything common in Portuguese. Both of those (rural one and the abbreviation/archaic one) are not typical of Portuguese in general.

@Lambie - Yes, I was illustrating that at some point in time in Portugal (not in Brazil) the word was written closely to what Wiktionary presents as phonetic transcription. You seem to be focussed on a phonemic difference, although the dictionary contradicts you. -But in fact I don't get what you ultimately mean. Do you mean that N is not assimilated and the previous U is not nasalized? What is your transcription then? Portuguese is famous for this process, and I was looking for a smaller similar process in Romanian which the transcriptions don't properly reflect or not enough.

@Lambie - Is this pronunciation what you'd call proper Portuguese?

@AdamBittlingmayer - Would you say that this Portuguese pronunciation involves no nasalization? A Portuguese commenting here seems to say that no. I beg to differ, but I'd say that ”quantitatively” there is not much more than in Romanian "bandit".

I don't hear anything too nasalized in a careful mainstream Portuguese pronunciation of mundo either.  Though there are definitely speakers that say it like muudu during normal speech.  Whereas the Romanian clip is basically ban dit, very clear, not comparable to French at all.

I don't hear anything too nasalized in a careful mainstream Portuguese pronunciation of mundo either.  - Does that mean that the Wiktionary is wrong or not applying to "mainstream" Portuguese? - And do you also hear the Portuguese "mundo" as mun du?

@AdamBittlingmayer - Notwithstanding the useless discussions to the contrary with the other commentator, the Portuguese correct transcription is the same as in the wiktionary https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/mundo

The phonetic rendition of mundo and fundo are mũdu andˈfũdu respectively. And mũdu also happens to be an archaic way of writing mundo. mundo/mudo =
world/dumb (as in deaf and dumb) = mũdu and mudu. The tilde ~ in Portuguese signals nasalization. What is useless is being aggressive.

Til (~) – Também conhecido como “tilde”, é usado nas vogais para indicar nasalidade. Não necessariamente é usado na vogal tônica. Til  (~)  aka tilde is used over vowels to indicate nasality. Not necessarily on the tonic vowel.

@AdamBittlingmayer I can assure you 100% that mundo is nasalized. If you don't nasalize the n, you sound like a yankee. It sounds like mun-dough. Being able to nasalize the n followed by d is what makes a native accent sound native. /n/ and /m/ in Portuguese are nasals.

Here's an article about nasals in Portuguese. They suggest holding a finger up to your nose. Of course, it's written for Portuguese speakers. https://www.ceale.fae.ufmg.br/glossarioceale/verbetes/nasalidade Sorry, but it's too much to translate.

I am confused.  Most of the discussion is about phonetic issues rather than phonemic issues.  Maybe I am missing something.  My understanding is that most linguists analyze Portuguese with both oral and nasal vowels and Romanian with only oral vowels.  Isn't that enough to justify the different phonemic transcriptions, given that nasalization is prominent feature of Portuguese pronunciation regardless of dialect?

@Lambie - What you say in the last comments (The phonetic rendition of mundo and fundo are mũdu andˈfũdu respectively.- The tilde ~ in Portuguese signals nasalization) is exactly what my Wiktionary link and my question said vut that (unless there is some confusion) you denied initially. - Agreeing Portuguese nasalization is a well-established fact, I just point out  how it is marked even in phenemic transcription, while a similar case in Romanian is not even marked by the phonetic one.

@Vegawatcher - I am referring to the phonetic transcriptions in Romanian, like [kɨnˈta]  for cânta. The fonemic /kɨnˈta/ is acceptable maybe, as separating the syllables we have cân-ta, where N is heard as in English I can. But in the sound of the whole word (and isn't that what phonemic transcriptions are for?) there shouldn't be noted a such N more than it is for Portuguese "mundo" or English "bank"! - What am I getting wrong?

What you are getting wrong is that the n in Portuguese  and in Roumanian are not the same n.

@Lambie - I never tried to say they are the same (type), just that there is about the same level of deviation from the more common N ([n]), worth marking somehow for Romanian too, at least in the phonetic transcription. When discussing generally people agree that Romanian has complex phonetics, not the same, but comparable to Portuguese by the distance from say Italian, but we don't really see that in phonetic transcription: I just think that complexity is underrepresented in the phonetic notation. (I won't ask you again about what I see as the contradictions in the comments.)

You'll only get a phonemic transcription like /ˈmũ.du/ in a language that can be analyzed as having nasal vowel phonemes. This is arguably the case for Portuguese, whereas I don't think anyone has ever argued that for Romanian.
The reason why vowel nasalization can be argued to be phonemic in Portuguese is because there are cases of phonemically distinctive surface contrasts between oral and nasalized vowels (or diphthongs) with no following nasal consonant.
However, that doesn't mean that Portuguese nasal vowels are never followed by a nasal consonant. It seems like there may in fact be a phonetic nasal consonant in words like mundo. But if you take the view that the vowel is phonemically nasalized, we can consider the phonetic nasal consonant to be a predictable, non-phonemic transition between the nasalized vowel and the following stop.
You could instead analyze the vowel as being predictably nasalized before a nasal consonant phoneme. In general, it's often not obvious whether nasalized vowels are derived at some "level" of the phonology from some other underlying representation (such as a vowel + nasal consonant sequence), so you can often encounter competing phonemic analyses of nasalized vowels.
Garcia 2017:9 ("Weight gradience and stress in Portuguese"), citing  Battisti 1997, claims that in "the standard approach to nasality in Portuguese", the nasal vowel in a word like fã "is underlyingly bisegmental" /aN/.
